# Unable to Create docker container on overlay network using static ip

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Previous using Docker 17.05, I was able to create overlay network with subnet 10.0.7.0/24 and then I was able to create a container with IP 10.0.7.2.

Now I am using Docker 18.03, I am able to create overlay network with subnet 10.0.7.0/24. But I am not able to create a container with IP 10.0.7.2.
I know that 10.0.7.1 is gateway IP. But what is 10.0.7.2 is being used for in new Docker(18.03).

please, can anybody explain why this happening?

On Docker 18.03,
`mynet` is my overlay network

```
> docker inspect mynet
[
    {
        "Name": "mynet",
        "Id": "4lq0j7thvyb8dkwt0zbbvgski",
        "Created": "2018-03-29T09:27:41.369349452Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.7.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.7.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4102"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

`docker run` is showing this error:

```
> docker run -dit --name mycon --network mynet --ip 10.0.7.2 ubuntu:16.04
caebeda51357d8e53f11fb765c8b4a65bd6c37d6746dbbdd1b4b8be7e6235a44
docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you managed to fixed this in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the swarm node is set to `availability=drain`.

The issue is documented [here](https://success.docker.com/article/context-deadline-exceeded-error-observed-while-starting-container-on-drained-node)

Otherwise, in 18.03, I have not faced this issue.

The following network works for me if `availability` is set to active, and I hit your issue if it is set to `drain`.

```
docker inspect ovr2 [
    {
        "Name": "ovr2",
        "Id": "28a5i9gcnys642u059ltfcjut",
        "Created": "2018-11-20T16:26:07.458744293Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.7.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.7.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": null
    } ]
```

Comment: Hm, sadly my node was already in the `active` state. My mystery deepens.

Comment: @mlissner that makes two of us. Have you been able to resolve this problem?